# Remove image drawn on Highchart

Tags: highcharts

I have drawn one image on high-chart using `chart.render.img` method of high-chart. Now after clicking on button I want to update the coordinates of this img. But, there is no update function for image, I am trying to remove and again add it with new coordinates. So I have stored img in one array and using this array element I am trying to remove the image. 
But It is not working.

```
var symbol = new Array();
symbol[0]= chart.renderer.image('assets/shared/images/green-line.png', xpoint, offset, width,height);
symbol[0].add();
```

Now after this i want to update the xpoint, offset, width & height. So I am removing this img.
 `$(symbol[0].element).remove();`
Then I want to again add it using add method with new coordinates. This remove is not working.

Comment: So only what you need is move img ?

Comment: Got a JSFiddle for us to try out?

Answer (score 1):

Just call "destroy" method:

```
symbol[0].destroy();
```